# ZFS raidz3 on proxmox having IO issues

Tags: zfs, io, proxmox

I'm running Proxmox 6.2-11 with 256GB ECC RAM and the following raidz3 pool:

```
pool: rpool
state: ONLINE
scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 15:25:14 with 0 errors on Sun Jan 10 15:49:29 2021
config:

NAME STATE READ WRITE CKSUM
rpool ONLINE 0 0 0
raidz3-0 ONLINE 0 0 0
ata-HGST_HUS726T6TALE6L4_V8JDUHAR-part4 ONLINE 0 0 0
ata-HGST_HUS726T6TALE6L4_V8JDWWAR-part4 ONLINE 0 0 0
ata-HGST_HUS726T6TALE6L4_V8JB5AYR-part4 ONLINE 0 0 0
ata-HGST_HUS726T6TALE6L4_V8JBYYTR-part4 ONLINE 0 0 0
ata-ST6000NM0115-1YZ110_ZAD9MHXH-part4 ONLINE 0 0 0
ata-ST6000NM0115-1YZ110_ZAD9M248-part4 ONLINE 0 0 0
ata-ST6000NM0115-1YZ110_ZAD9MQ9E-part4 ONLINE 0 0 0
ata-ST6000NM0115-1YZ110_ZAD9MN5A-part4 ONLINE 0 0 0

errors: No known data errors


NAME SIZE ALLOC FREE CKPOINT EXPANDSZ FRAG CAP DEDUP HEALTH ALTROOT
rpool 43.6T 9.71T 33.9T - - 10% 22% 1.00x ONLINE -
```

On the proxmox host from few weeks I feel a big increase in the IO wait (2-3%), seeing txg_sync maxing at 95-99.99% IO via iotop. On one of the guest instances /Debian/ I can see jdb2/vda1-8 having again 99.99% most of the time.

Plenty of RAM available on both guest & host. What can the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to PVE 6.3 (ZFS 0.8.4 -> 0.8.6) and the issue is gone for now.

Comment: just as a guess, try `zpool iostat -v` to see if that a drive which is hanging